# Use sscanf to read optional number

Tags: c

I know `sscanf()` in C doesn't support regular expression. However, I wonder if there is a way to read an `int` that is optional as follows:

For example:

```
cost apple
cost apple, 3  // comma, and 3 are optional
```

if I use

```
sscanf("cost %s \, %d" , &product , &value);
```

It will fail because ', 3' might not appear on string.

Is there away to fix that on one `sscanf()` shot?

Comment: The code will fail because you are not providing valid string to scan from, and I wonder what type `product` has.

Comment: What shoudl happen if only the `,` was there like `"cost apple,"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sscanf` will fail due to another reasons, and once it is fixed, it won't fail for ', 3' not appearing on the string.

I suggest you should get return value from `sscanf`, and then use it for determining how many data are read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(const char *data) {
    char product[100];
    int value;
    int ssret;

    ssret = sscanf(data, "cost %99[^,], %d", product, &value);
    switch(ssret) {
        case 1:
            printf("product = %s\n", product);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("product = %s, value = %d\n", product, value);
            break;
        default:
            puts("sscanf() failed to read");
            break;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    test("cost apple");
    test("cost apple, 3");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the full version ("%s %d"). sscanf will return the number of variables assigned. From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

> On success, the function returns the number of items in the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) in the case of a matching failure.

So if you only have "cost apple" as an input, sscanf would return 1 and populate `product`. Whereas with "cost apple, 3" it would return 2 and populate `product` and `value`.

You have a few problems with your code too. First, the first argument to sscanf should be the string to read from. Not the format string. Second, the format string needs to be a string, use double quotes ("). Third, don't escape the comma, that's not a valid escape sequence.

You can't have that comma in the format string anyway. The `%s` specifier reads characters until the first whitespace character it sees. So an input string of `"cost apple, 3"` would need a format specifier of `"cost %s %d"`. You would then have to get the substring without the comma in order to get the actual product name.

Answer (score 1):

First of, the prototype of [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) is `int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);`

So try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char product[100] = {0};
        int value = 0;

        sscanf("cost apple", "cost %[^,\n], %d", product, &value);
        printf("cost %s, %d\n", product, value);

        sscanf("cost apple, 3", "cost %[^,\n], %d", product, &value);
        printf("cost %s, %d\n", product, value);

        return 0;
}
```

The `%[^,\n]` in `sscanf()` match every `char` besides `,` and `\n`. The  before `%d` is used to discard all whitespace characters.

Also, using `&product` will cause undefined behavior, so just write `product` instead.

## EDIT

It's always a good habit to check the return value of `sscanf()`. Although you will code will compile and run successfully without doing this, it will tell you which information is useful and which is not.

Comment: `sscanf("cost ,", "cost %[^,\n], %d", product, &value); printf("cost %s, %d\n", product, value);` would lead to printing an uninitialized string.  Better to check the result of `sscanf()`.

Comment: I'm apologize ... I made a mistake .... I fixed it now ... it works fine now ... Thank you very much. I deleted the previous comment.